# Ceph Nautilus : How to enable the Ceph MGR dashboard

Tags: ceph, cephfs

I have recently installed Ceph Nautilus.

```
ceph version 14.2.1 (d555a9489eb35f84f2e1ef49b77e19da9d113972) nautilus (stable)
```

I cannot see any "dashboard" module (neither in enabled nor in disabled state). I an checking through "ceph mgr module ls"

If I try to enable it, I get following error.

```
[user@system mydir]$ ceph mgr module enable dashboard
Error ENOENT: all mgr daemons do not support module 'dashboard', pass --force to force enablement
```

How can I enable the dashboard module?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Install the appropriate package from the below [link](http://download.ceph.com/rpm-nautilus/el7/noarch/)

```
# rpm -Uvh http://download.ceph.com/rpm-nautilus/el7/noarch/ceph-mgr-dashboard-14.2.1-0.el7.noarch.rpm
```

Note: it will ask for few dependencies, install with yum/apt package manager and then execute the above command.

2. Enable the ceph mgr dashboard

```
# ceph mgr module enable dashboard 
# ceph mgr module ls
```

3. Create self-signed certificate

```
# sudo ceph dashboard create-self-signed-cert 
Self-signed certificate created
```

4. Create a user for Dashboard

```
Example: [ceph dashboard ac-user-create (username) (password) administrator]

# ceph dashboard ac-user-create cent password administrator 
{"username": "cent", "lastUpdate": 1560292901, "name": null, "roles": ["administrator"], "password": "$2b$12$w60gItcbKd6PULNYI9McmOBMiAzFoKJ9T9XGva8vC6dxIyqMsE4kK", "email": null}

# ceph mgr services 
{
    "dashboard": "https://ceph-mgr:8443/"
}
```

Note: Here you can access with IP address of ceph-mgr node, instead of hostname.

5. Make sure firewall port is open

```
# firewall-cmd --add-port=8443/tcp --permanent 
# firewall-cmd --reload
```

6. Open the dashboard url in any browser

```
https://ceph-mgr:8443 or https://192.168.1.10:8443
```

7. Enter the username: *cent* and password: *password*

Here you go...